# MySQL not picking correct row count from index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, explain, database-indexes

I have a following table

```
CREATE TABLE `test_series_analysis_data` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mappingId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `packageId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sectionName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `marksObtained` float NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `testMetaData` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`,`mappingId`,`packageId`,`sectionName`),
  KEY `rank_index` (`mappingId`,`packageId`,`sectionName`,`marksObtained`),
  KEY `mapping_package` (`mappingId`,`packageId`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Following is the output of the explain for the queries:

```
explain select rank 
from (
   select email, @i:=@i+1 as rank 
   from test_series_analysis_data ta 
   join (select @i:=0) va 
   where mappingId = ?1 
   and packageId = ?2 
   and sectionName = ?3 
   order by marksObtained desc
) as inter 
where inter.email = ?4;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys              | key         | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                | <auto_key0> | 767     | const |    10 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | NULL       | system | NULL                       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  |     1 |   100.00 | Using filesort           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ta         | NULL       | ref    | rank_index,mapping_package | rank_index  | 4       | const | 20160 |     1.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Query optimizer could have used both indexes but rank_index is a covering index so it got picked. What surprises me is the output of the following query:

```
explain select rank 
from ( 
  select email, @i:=@i+1 as rank 
  from test_series_analysis_data ta use index (mapping_package) 
  join (select @i:=0) va 
  where mappingId = ?1 
  and packageId = ?2 
  and sectionName = ?3 
  order by marksObtained desc
) as inter 
where inter.email = ?4;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>     | <auto_key0>     | 767     | const |    10 |   100.00 | NULL                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | NULL       | system | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL  |     1 |   100.00 | Using filesort        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ta         | NULL       | ref    | mapping_package | mapping_package | 4       | const | 19434 |     1.00 | Using index condition |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL       | NULL   | NULL            | NULL            | NULL    | NULL  |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Why are there `rows` lesser (19434<20160) when the index being used is mapping_package. rank_index can better select what is required so the row count should be lesser in rank_index.

So does this mean mapping_package index is better than rank_index for the given query?

Does it have any effect that sectionName is a varchar so both indexes should give similar performance?

Also I am assuming `Using index condition` is selecting only few rows from index and scanning some more. While in case `Using where; Using index`, optimizer has to only read the index and not table to get rows and then it is selecting some data. Then why `Using where` is missing while using  rank_index?

Moreover why is the key_len for mapping_package is 4 when there are only two columns in the index?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Which query (with or without the `use index`) runs faster?

Answer (score 1):

`(19434<20160)` -- Both of those numbers are estimates.  It is unusual for them to be that close.  I'll bet if you did `ANALYZE TABLE`, both would change, possibly changing the inequality.

Notice something else:  `Using where; Using index` versus `Using index condition`.

But first, let me remind you that, in InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` columns are tacked onto the secondary key.  So, effectively you have

```
KEY `rank_index`      (`mappingId`,`packageId`,`sectionName`,`marksObtained`,`email`)
KEY `mapping_package` (`mappingId`,`packageId`,`email`,`sectionName`)
```

Now let's decide what the optimal index should be:
   where mappingId = ?1 
   and packageId = ?2 
   and sectionName = ?3 
   order by marksObtained desc

- First, the `=` parts of `WHERE`:  `mappingId`, `packageId`, `sectionName`, in any order;
- Then the `ORDER BY` column(s):  `marksObtained`
- Bonus:  Finally if `email` (the only other column mentioned anywhere in the `SELECT`) is in the key, it will be "Covering".

This says that `rank_index` is "perfect", and the other index is not so good.  Alas, `EXPLAIN` does not clearly say that.

You, too, could have figured this out -- all you needed is to study my blog: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql  (Sorry; it's getting late, and I am getting cheeky.)

Other tips:

- Don't blindly use `(255)`.  When a tmp table is needed, this can make the the tmp table bigger, hence less efficient.  Lower the limit to something reasonable.  Or...
- If this is a huge table, you really ought to 'normalize' the strings, replacing them with maybe a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`.  This will improve performance in other ways, such as decreasing costly I/O.  (OK, 20 rows is pretty small, so this may not apply.)

Why is `key_len` 4?  That implies that one column was used, namely the 4-byte `INT` `mappingId`.  I would have expected it to use the second column, too.  So, I am stumped.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` may provide more clues.

Comment: Can you point to a mysql ref indication tacking of keys? I did ran analyze tables and numbers did not change. Indeed it was `Using where; Using index` that made me think `rank_index` is indeed better.
Also, this is not such a huge table (like only 5L entries). after index search, < 5000 rows are returned.

Comment: Perhaps this?:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html  (last section of that page)

Comment: 5L = 5 lakh = 500K?

Comment: `EXPLAIN`, even the `JSON` format does not always provide enough information to answer performance questions like yours.